# Debugging the triangle wave generation using ISL7044

Tags: voltage, analog, pwm, comparator, integrator

I am trying to simulate an Analog PWM circuit as shown in this TI application note.

Link attached here => [Analog PWM TI Report](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau508/slau508.pdf?ts=1710746485045&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

However, I have a requirement to achieve the same using ISL70444 OP-AMPS only (and using them as comparators, wherever needed). [ISL70444 Datasheet attached here](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl70444seh-isl73444seh-datasheet)

When I am trying to simulate the circuit in PSpice, I am facing issue near the triangle generation block. The triangle wave is getting distorted and not getting formed properly. I am attaching the simulation result and snapshot of the schematic below:

[image: Triangle Generation Block]

[image: Simulation Result]

The green wave is the triangle being generated and the pink waveform is the square waveform being integrated. I believe that there's an issue with the integration of the square pulse when I am trying to use ISL7044.

Can anyone please help me figure out what the issue here could be?

Comment: Capacitor C3 isn't too low ... Should be "greater".

Comment: Can you please provide a scope track of VREF? I assume the internal antiparallel diodes inside the ISL70444 between IN+ and IN- will allow current flow into and out of VREF from the oposite inputs.